# Using jQuery Cookie to store checkbox state

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cookies, checkbox

How do you use the jQuery Cookie plugin to ensure a checked checkbox remains checked when refreshing the page or leaving and returning to the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using the [`$.cookie`](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) jQuery plugin...

```
var checkbox = $('#your-form :checkbox:first'),
    checkboxCookieName = 'checkbox-state';

checkbox.prop('checked', +$.cookie(checkboxCookieName));

checkbox.click(function() {
   $.cookie(checkboxCookieName, +this.checked);
});
```

Comment: There is unwanted `+` while setting the checkbox `checked` prop.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli How is it unwanted? I want to store `'0'` or `'1'` for ease of converting back from string to something *falsy*.

Comment: Also note that .prop() was added in jQuery 1.6. If you using more older plugin it can be replaced with .attr()